# ViewGroup{TextView,...}.getMeasuredHeight gives wrong value is smaller than real height

Tags: android

```
  { January 14, 2011... I have given up to use setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView},
  instead, I don't put my listview in a scrollview, and then just put other contents
  into a listview by using ListView.addHeaderView() and ListView.addFooterView(). 
  http://dewr.egloos.com/5467045 }
```

ViewGroup(the ViewGroup is containing TextViews having long text except line-feed-character).getMeasuredHeight returns wrong value... that is smaller than real height.

how to get rid of this problem?

here is the java code:

```
    /*
    I have to set my listview's height by myself. because
    if a listview is in a scrollview then that will be
    as short as the listview's just one item.
    */
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int count = listAdapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

and here is the list_item_comments.xml:

Answer (score 18):

The question is rather old, but I had similar problem, so I'll describe what was wrong.
Actually, parameters in listItem.measure() are used wrong, you should set something like this:

```
listItem.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
```

However, be careful with unspecified width measure spec, it will ignore all layout params and even screen dimensions, so to get correct height, first get maximum width View can use and call measure() this way:

```
listItem.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```

Comment: @user711058 i have same problem but thissolution is not working for me

Comment: This answer helped me solve a problem I've been working on for a while. My problem came from a lack of understanding of how measure worked. 

My child view used match_parent for its width, but my measure call used MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) for the width parameter.

Changing the width parameter to MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), allowed me to get the correct height from the view by calling view.getMeasuredHeight().

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand how the `measure` method works and could solve my problem

Comment: Thanks you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution i have found so far.
http://syedrakibalhasan.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-width-and-height-dimensions.html

Answer (score 0):

It also gives wrong value when Your xml file of listview item has padding. Remove padding, try using margin and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As @DalvikDroid mensioned, using the following method fixed the problem:

```
listItem.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```